# Cannot use WKAlertAction and Alerts WatchKit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, watchkit

This may be a supremely stupid question, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why I can't get these following lines of code to work:

```
WKAlertAction *act = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:WKAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(void){
        NSLog(@"ALERT ACTION ");
    }];

 NSArray *actions = @[act];

[self presentAlertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert actions:alertActions];
```

When I put them into my InterfaceController the compiler doesn't recognize neither the alertWithTitle: method nor the `presentAlertControllerWithTitle` method, nor things like `WKAlertActionStyleCancel`. WatchKit is imported, so shouldn't these be too?

Comment: Apart from the alertActions/actions typo, are you targeting the watchOS 2 SDK?  This wasn't available for watchOS 1.

Comment: @PetahChristian Yes, I'm targeting WatchOS 2.